# Why my player is stuttering when moving and rotating at the same time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script is attached to my player character and make the player start rotating and moving at the same time either when entering/exiting a collider.

When the player start rotating and moving everything is stuttering. so i can't figure out what cause it and if the player is stuttering or the camera maybe.

The stuttering only when the player rotating and moving the same time when the rotating is over also the stuttering is over. it's only the small part when the player start the rotating and the moving.

I will provide the script some screenshots and a very small short video clip showing the problem.

The script that attached to the player :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;
using Cinemachine;

public class DistanceCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform objectToRotatetowards;
    public float slowDownLerpDuration;
    public float speedUpLerpDuration;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public GameObject descriptionTextImage;
    public TextMeshProUGUI text;
    public ThirdPersonUserControl thirdPersonUserControl;

    private Animator anim;
    private float timeElapsed = 0;
    private float startValue = 1;
    private float endValue = 0;
    private float valueToLerp = 0;
    private bool startRotating = false;
    private bool slowOnBack = true;
    private bool exited = false;
    private Vector3 exitPosition;
    private float distance;
    private bool rotateTowards = false;
    private bool rotateBackwards = false;
    private bool rotateTowardsObject = false;


    void Start()
    {
        anim = transform.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (startRotating)
        {
            if (rotateTowards)
            {
                if (rotateTowardsObject)
                {
                    Vector3 targetDirection = objectToRotatetowards.position - transform.position;
                    float singleStep = 3f * Time.deltaTime;
                    Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetDirection, singleStep, 0.0f);
                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);
                }

                if (rotateBackwards)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(DoRotate(2f));
                    rotateBackwards = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (exitPosition != new Vector3(0, 0, 0) && slowOnBack)
        {
            distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, exitPosition);
        }

        if (distance > 5 && slowOnBack)
        {
            slowOnBack = false;
            StartCoroutine(SlowDown());
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "NoExit")
        {
            rotateTowardsObject = true;
            rotateBackwards = false;
            descriptionTextImage.SetActive(true);
            if (other.TryGetComponent(out ColliderInfo info))
            {
                text.text = info.onExitText;
                rotateTowards = info.rotateTowards;
            }
            RepositionPlayer();
        }
        else if (other.tag == "NoEntry")
        {
            OnPlayerRepositioned();
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "NoExit")
        {
            OnPlayerRepositioned();
        }
        else if (other.tag == "NoEntry")
        {
            rotateTowardsObject = false;
            rotateBackwards = true;
            descriptionTextImage.SetActive(true);
            if (other.TryGetComponent(out ColliderInfo info))
            {
                text.text = info.onEnterText;
                rotateTowards = info.rotateTowards;
            }
            RepositionPlayer();
        }
    }

    private void RepositionPlayer()
    {
        exited = true;
        slowOnBack = true;
        exitPosition = transform.position;
        thirdPersonUserControl.enabled = false;
        StartCoroutine(SlowDown());
    }

    private void OnPlayerRepositioned()
    {
        exited = false;
        startRotating = false;
        text.text = "";
        descriptionTextImage.SetActive(false);
    }

    IEnumerator SlowDown()
    {
        timeElapsed = 0;

        while (timeElapsed < slowDownLerpDuration)
        {
            valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / slowDownLerpDuration);
            anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;

            yield return null;
        }

        if (exited)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);

            startRotating = true;
            StartCoroutine(SpeedUp());
        }

        if (slowOnBack == false)
        {
            thirdPersonUserControl.enabled = true;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SpeedUp()
    {
        timeElapsed = 0;

        while (timeElapsed < speedUpLerpDuration)
        {
            valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(endValue, startValue, timeElapsed / speedUpLerpDuration);
            anim.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator DoRotate(float time)
    {
        var startRotation = transform.rotation;

        var newRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(180, Vector3.up) * transform.rotation;

        var progress = 0f;

        while (progress < 1)
        {
            progress += Time.deltaTime / time;

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(startRotation, newRotation, progress);

            yield return null;
        }

        transform.rotation = newRotation;
    }
}
```

Screenshot of my player components settings :

[image: player components settings]

I did a test no when i add a regular Camera as child of the player and then try it it seems like there is not stuttering :

but when switching back to the cinemachine freelook camera then it's stuttering.
In this short video clip in the start i'm using regular camera without stuttering and then

From 1:09 minutes i'm using the cinemachine camera and then it's stuttering.
The stuttering it self start at 1:20 minute.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WjWebb_6kY

The cinemachine camera settings screenshots :
The parent object of all the cameras have this script attached :

[image: parent cameras script attached]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;
public class CamerasControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CinemachineFreeLook playerCameraGameplay;
    public float clampMin;
    public float clampMax;
    public float pitch;
    public float speed;

    void Update()
    {
        pitch += speed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
        pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, clampMin, clampMax);
        playerCameraGameplay.GetRig(1).GetCinemachineComponent<CinemachineComposer>().m_TrackedObjectOffset.y = pitch;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to interpolate your rotation and position

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Mathf.Lerp and Slerp  is not good as i'm doing now ? what should i do instead ?

Comment: You need to move from `FixedUpdate` to `Update`.  `FixedUpdate` is for dealing with physics, however you are not dealing with physics, you are dealing with transform.  Also, you are using `Time.deltaTime` in `FixedUpdate`.  This is a big no-no.  For `FixedUpdate`, use `Time.fixedDeltaTime` instead.